# using a join table for rails select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm passing in a collection of join tables into my rails select and it looks like this:

```
= select_tag :editing_channel, options_from_collection_for_select(@channel_users, :id, :channel_id)
```

That works fine, but it's showing a channel_id in the view.  I would like to show the channels name.  Which is just channel.name, how can i do accomplish that?

I would like to display channel.nae

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :channel_users
    has_many :channels, through: :channel_users
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channel_users
  has_many :users, through: :channel_users
end
```

Comment: What is your model and attributes?

Comment: I edited my post to show the models

Comment: What are the attributes in channel model?

Comment: `Channel(id: integer, name: string, state: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`

Comment: Try `= select_tag :editing_channel, options_from_collection_for_select(@channel_users, :id, :name)`

Comment: I gave that a shot.  `undefined method name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select_tag :editing_channel, options_for_select(@channel_users.map { |cu| [cu.channel.name, cu.id] })
```

Comment: I tried something similar to that.  Get this error: `undefined local variable or method channel`

Comment: can you replace channel.name by @channel_users.channel.name

Comment: @hoanewton `@channel_users.channel.name`, i think, will return error.

Comment: That displays the correct channel name, but I don't want to use the channel_id.  I need the channel_user.id  aka :id

Comment: if so just replace cu.channel.id by 'cu.id' like the edited code above :)

Answer (score 0):

From API dock:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name')
# => <option value="#{person.id}">#{person.name}</option>
```

in your case it should be like this:

```
= select_tag :editing_channel, options_from_collection_for_select(@channel_users, :id, :name)
```

Comment: `I gave that a shot. undefined method name`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested by me, but try this.

Use the `collection_select` helper, in your view,  as follows:

```
collection_select(:channel_ids, Channel.all, :id, :name)
```

In your `User` model, ensure that you've added `channel_ids: []` to your `user_params` method, so that the `channel_ids` can be mass assigned to the User model.